# How to connect two ipads without using Wi-Fi to send data from one iPad to other iPad?

Tags: ipad

I am new to iPad applications, I am doing one application which requires to send data from one ipad to another ipad. my application involves, when one person is presenting some presentation in his ipad it has to visible to all other persons which are having my application in their iPads. here we have one constraint that is we don't want to connect through Wi-Fi. I don't know how to connect two iPads without Wi-Fi..

Please help me.. Thank you..